# How did the philosophy of Ancient Greece influence Ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-philosophy

Mostly, I'm curious about the lasting impacts of classical philosophy, but in the name of brevity and specifics I'll confine my question to the influence classical Greek philosophy had on the next major Western civilization: Ancient Rome.

What I wonder is, in what ways did Ancient Greek philosophy influence Ancient Rome, in terms of things like political philosophy, science, art, and religion?

Comment: Basically, there were a widespread cultural influence of Ancient Greece on the ancient Roman society : poetry, science, philosophy, etc. due to the domination of Greek peninsula after the Battle of Corinth (146 BC) when Macedonia became a Roman province. You can see [The Cambridge Companion to Greek and Roman Philosophy](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/the-cambridge-companion-to-greek-and-roman-philosophy/7ECE0928CDC6A80441F99B8CF19BB701).

Comment: Some info also into :LLOYD GERSON (editor) [The Cambridge History of Philosophy in Late Antiquity](https://books.google.it/books?id=Jm0CBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2010).

Answer (score 1):

There is no doubt that Ancient Greece played a hugely influential role in shaping the course of Western civilisation. In fact, it could be argued that without the Greeks, our modern world would look very different indeed. One key area in which they had a profound impact was philosophy.

For the ancient Romans, philosophy was not just an academic pursuit but something that was deeply intertwined with their way of life. It was used as a tool to help them make sense of the world around them and to find answers to the big questions of life.

Many Roman thinkers were heavily influenced by the ideas of their Greek counterparts. In politics, for instance, Cicero was inspired by Plato's vision of an ideal republic, while in science, the Roman physician Galen used Aristotle's theories to develop his own ideas about medicine.

The impact of Greek philosophy can also be seen in other areas of Roman culture, such as art and religion. The Stoic philosophy of Marcus Aurelius, for example, inspired a new wave of thinkers who emphasised the importance of living in harmony with nature. And the Neo-Platonist philosopher Plotinus helped to revive interest in the ancient mysteries of Egypt and Greece.

So, as you can see, the influence of classical Greek philosophy on Ancient Rome was far-reaching and profound. It shaped the way they thought about the world and helped to shape the course of Western civilisation.